# Using A different Criteria for Every Query on google sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets

So I recently started learning to work with Queries on Google Sheets and I must say I'm having a lot of fun with it but I came across a new issue that I am struggling to fix.

So, what I'm trying to do as example in below picture. I want to make a query, for example:
I want to see the total amount of items Anna sold for every Item. So this would be my Starting Query:

```
=QUERY(Test_Page!A:D, "Select B, SUM(C) Where A = 'Anna' GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC")
```

Now I also would like to See the Total of each Color sold per Item, I tried to do this for every new column/data requested to see is a requiring a new item. What I tried was:

```
=QUERY(Test_Page!A:D, "Select B, SUM(C) Where A = 'Anna' GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC, SUM(C) where D = 'red'")
```

didnt work

```
=QUERY(Test_Page!A:D, "Select B, SUM(C) where D = 'red', SUM(C) Where A = 'Anna' GROUP BY B ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC")
```

didnt work

So I went looking around on the internet but it seems like nobody ever tried to do this or maybe it just does not work at all, I do not know.

```
Anna    Pencil  3   red
Peter   Chair   6   blue
Ben Table   9   green
Bob Car 6   purple
Anna    Pen 3   red
Peter   Pencil  6   blue
Ben Chair   9   green
Bob Table   6   purple
Anna    Car 3   red
Peter   Pen 6   blue
Ben Pencil  9   green
Bob Chair   6   purple
Anna    Table   3   red
Peter   Car 6   blue
Ben Pen 9   green
Bob Pencil  6   purple
Anna    Chair   3   red
Peter   Table   6   blue
Ben Car 9   green
Bob Pen 6   purple
Anna    Pencil  3   red
Peter   Chair   6   blue
Ben Table   9   green
```

[Picture of the info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSIIl.png)

Sorry if my description is not clear enough, first time posting here!

Answer (score 0):

*If you are specifically looking for `Anna` & `red`, slight modification to your formula would be:*

```js
=QUERY(Test_Page!A:D, "Select B, SUM(C) Where A = 'Anna' AND D = 'red' GROUP BY B,D ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC")
```

*If `Anna` had more than one color & you wish to see all of their total grouped; then you may try (`sample data modified for demonstration`):*

```js
=QUERY(Test_Page!A:D, "Select B, D, SUM(C) where A = 'Anna' GROUP BY B,D ORDER BY SUM(C) DESC label sum(C) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the data I showed is just a small list, my actual data I would be using is a few hundred to thousand list long so it will have multiple data for "Anna" + "Pencil" + "Red".


Ideally, I want to see data like the following: Anna Items - Total Items sold - Total Items Red color Sold - Total Items Blue color sold - Etc for all colors.


So my main question: Is this possible in 1 query or just 1 formulla/line of code (however long it gets)? If yes, how haha, if no, could u provide me with any other solutions?

Comment: Doesn't the second suggested formula do exactly that?!

Comment: It does in a way, but, this will give me a list that is very hard to look at, I want a query where I can see 1. The Item sold 2. The total amount of items told 3. Items of the color red 4. Items of the color Blue 5. Items of the color Green 6. Items of the color purple. So I can inmidetly see which products get sold the most and which color is the most sold of this and which color doesnt do good at all of this product to easily track down without doing too much effort what is good or bad. The colors are very limited, not many, but the products are a huge list in reality.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: So, instead of having 3 colums, which shows me 1. Item 2. Color of that 1 item. 3. Amount sold of that 1 item of that 1 color. I want to have 6 in this case.